# How to run a html file from php?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to figure out how we can run a html file within a php script.

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Comment: Isn't the whole point of server side languages like PHP to produce HTML?

Comment: HTML is not executable code, so it can't be "run". Are you asking about including an HTML file somewhere else, using PHP?

Comment: @Kobi no, the point of server side languages is to do things on the server. That includes but is not limited to producing HTML files. Can just as well produce JSON, XML or nothing at all.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a real question.

Answer (score 7):

```
include('my_html_file.html');
```